# Android Studio cannot find cerfile, emulator doesn´t start

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I just got this problem while trying to test a project I been working on, yesterday didn´t have this problem

> Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find
>    certfile: C:\Users\yeyog.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be
>    disabled.
>
> Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a few minutes ago. Install your plugins if required, update the Android studio if required then uninstall the application from the emulator phone. Restart the android studio and re-run the code, it will respond as required. Update me, if you have any issues.

Also, you can invalidate caches and restart. Press File on the drop-down menu on top, then select invalidate caches and restart. Try again