# GRPC Server error while running android app on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

So, I am new to android and trying to run my first app. Created an empty activity project and tried to run it using the emulator. I am getting the following error:

> 23:20 Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot
>   find certfile: C:\Users\myUser\.android\emulator-grpc.cer security
>   will be disabled.
>
> 23:20 Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

I am have tried installing the latest SDK from SDK tools, restarted the system. Still not good. Can Someone help?

Android Studio Details:
Android Studio 3.6.1
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 27, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:

Comment: Look at [why-do-i-get-this-grpc-error-warning-emulatorservice-cpp448-cannot-find-cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306645/why-do-i-get-this-grpc-error-warning-emulatorservice-cpp448-cannot-find-cert). btw, I have the same issues, and for me it wasn't resolved.

Comment: Is it something with the latest update? I had the old android studio and everything was ok, until I updated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be quite a frequent recent problem, there are a few threads about it, for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306645/why-do-i-get-this-grpc-error-warning-emulatorservice-cpp448-cannot-find-cert) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366813/android-studio-cannot-find-cerfile-emulator-doesn%C2%B4t-start) among others.

I have had this problem myself, and what worked for me was to keep the emulator running, **uninstall the app** you just tried to run from within the emulator, and then **re-run it** from Android Studio (which will **re-install it** in the Android device in the emulator).  When re-installed, it works fine.

Others in the aforementioned threads seemed to have luck with choosing:

**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart** in Android Studio, but this did not make any difference for me.

I hope you find a solution.

Comment: After multiple attempts of your steps it worked great once. So, marking it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

A "Cold Boot Now" of AVD helps me. Tools > AVD Manager > "The drop-down on rigth side" > Cold Boot Now.

I still get the certfile error, but grpc works.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed now with the newest Updates for Canary Release of Android Studio (Emulator 30.0.10 Canary)!

See [Release Updates](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/04/emulator-30010-canary.html):

> - Removed prints about certs and GRPC on startup.