# App in Android Virtual Device continues to stop working

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

Extra context: using LibGDX engine in android studio. Updated android studio today and avd no longer works.

After I build my project and run the AVD the app crashes. I have gone into settings and tried to open the app from there which occasionally opens up the app and then promptly crashes (and the screen will pop up with a message that says the app keeps stopping - screenshot attached). Additionally, I get this error: Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554 - which I have checked through the following stackoverflow links but have struggled to fix the issue still. I have searched through stack overflow and have tried:

- cleaning the project and rebuilding it
- restarting android studio and then rerunning the code
- restarting the avd
- creating a new avd
- updating SDK tools (though I am uncertain if I have the right tools installed, will attach image of what I have installed)
- updating android studio (running version 3.6.1)
- invalidating caches and restarting (after deleting the app off of the emulator, and after reinstalling 
  the app on the emulator)

For context, I was looking at these stack overflow posts and have tried the suggestions that I mentioned
above, but I could have missed something:

- [Android Studio cannot find cerfile, emulator doesn´t start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366813/android-studio-cannot-find-cerfile-emulator-doesn%C2%B4t-start)
- [Why do I get this GRPC Error "WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile" when I start the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306645/why-do-i-get-this-grpc-error-warning-emulatorservice-cpp448-cannot-find-cert)
- [GRPC Server error while running andoid app on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60513178/grpc-server-error-while-running-andoid-app-on-emulator)
- [Error type 3 Error: Activity class {} does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)

Any help would be appreciated, and I would be happy to edit and provide more information if needed!

This is the snapshot of the error in the AVD mentioned above.

[image: This is the error whenever I try to launch the app]

This is a link to the picture of the SDK tools installed on my computer.
[SDK Tools installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8awL.png)

Edit:
I tried a new android studio project without LibGDX and the AVD worked fine.

I've followed this video for the setup of my LibGDX project: https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dp_hp6vMeewQ%26list%3DPL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl%26index%3D70&h=AT2_tH6gq08lg9Xnl0q0C6DJ5bnjySsbAvu0KmR9Jr6m8g8xGLzK5k39bMl5jdpQgFYHQcnd6t_rqixKPG6pTO1gYzPoBMN1MC_qzF8jUqtQITrsA-gU46c9zLHt90nZY8_ACbeRK33DmDvfGGQrYA

I've followed this video series for the tutorial I am working on - the AVD broke on this video: https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dp_hp6vMeewQ%26list%3DPL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl%26index%3D70&h=AT2_tH6gq08lg9Xnl0q0C6DJ5bnjySsbAvu0KmR9Jr6m8g8xGLzK5k39bMl5jdpQgFYHQcnd6t_rqixKPG6pTO1gYzPoBMN1MC_qzF8jUqtQITrsA-gU46c9zLHt90nZY8_ACbeRK33DmDvfGGQrYA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the links I posted and what I tried (cleaning the project, deleting the app from the emulator and invalidating caches and restarting android studio) actually do work.

The problem was that android studio did not understand my .tmx file (the file that will provide the map for my app) for some reason.

I realized this after clicking on the tmx file, as android studio displayed a prompt about downloading dependencies for the tmx file. Then all I did was download the suggested dependencies and then cleaned, deleted and invalidated/restarted and the AVD worked.